# Low number of site map links and none of mobile site map links indexed in the google

Tags: google-search-console, sitemap, google-index

There 2,521 sitemap URLs submit to the Google webmaster tools.
But they indexed only 548 URLs and 1,256 mobile sitemap URLs were submitted but none of it indexed. This shown in whole last month.

URLs has Status OK and no any errors.

Can anybody enplane why this happen? Is my sitemap code error or It's normal thing in Google webmaster tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly isn't unusual for there to be a proportion of content which isn't indexed, but such a high proportion does suggest problems with your site. Setting aside the mobile site for a moment, as a starting point I'd suggest:

- Check all URLs listed in the Sitemap are definitely valid (run the .xml file through an HTTP header checker, ideally).
- Look at the Index Status tool in GWT (**Health > Index Status**, click the **Advanced** tab). Are you seeing large amounts of content showing as "not selected", "blocked by robots" etc.?
- Do you have any content duplication issues?
- Have you had any messages from Google regarding suspicious back links, etc.?

The mobile site is more perplexing: that nothing is indexed suggests as serious problem somewhere, and a lot depends on the site configuration. Try the basic checks above to rule out simpler problems first.

If you can, share the site(s) address(es). Much easier to help if we can see the site first-hand.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Site as follows

Main site : http://www.john-anthony.com/

Mobile : http://m.john-anthony.com/

Comment: @miuranga Have you done what I've suggested so far? What were your results?

Comment: Yah. I checked. there are no any error regarding above points.

Comment: @miuranga Really? What about the duplication problem? Google is reporting _far_ more results than you say exist in total. I also found indexed content blocked by robots.txt, yet you say no errors. I'd suggest you hire an SEO to look at this for you.